# Laravel Spatie Permissions - Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_database.models' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-permission

I'm getting an error when using spatie permissions and trying to assign a role using:

```
$user->assignRole('admin');
```

The error is the following:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_database.models' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `models` where `user_id` = 38 and `model_type` = App\User)
```

Where is the value "models" being set?, that table doesn't exist but, where do I set the value?, I can't seem to find it, I have already checked inside `config/permission.php`.

My `permission` file is the following:

```
return [

'models' => [

    /*
     * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your permissions. Of course, it
     * is often just the "Permission" model but you may use whatever you like.
     *
     * The model you want to use as a Permission model needs to implement the
     * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` contract.
     */

    'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::class,

    /*
     * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your roles. Of course, it
     * is often just the "Role" model but you may use whatever you like.
     *
     * The model you want to use as a Role model needs to implement the
     * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role` contract.
     */

    'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,

],

'table_names' => [

    /*
     * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * table should be used to retrieve your roles. We have chosen a basic
     * default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
     */

    'roles' => 'roles',

    /*
     * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * table should be used to retrieve your permissions. We have chosen a basic
     * default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
     */

    'permissions' => 'permissions',

    /*
     * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * table should be used to retrieve your models permissions. We have chosen a
     * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
     */

    'users_has_permissions' => 'users_has_permissions',

    /*
     * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * table should be used to retrieve your models roles. We have chosen a
     * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
     */

    'users_has_roles' => 'users_has_roles',

    /*
     * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * table should be used to retrieve your roles permissions. We have chosen a
     * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
     */

    'role_has_permissions' => 'role_has_permissions',
],

'column_names' => [

    /*
     * Change this if you want to name the related model primary key other than
     * `model_id`.
     *
     * For example, this would be nice if your primary keys are all UUIDs. In
     * that case, name this `model_uuid`.
     */

    'model_morph_key' => 'user_id',
],

/*
 * When set to true, the required permission/role names are added to the exception
 * message. This could be considered an information leak in some contexts, so
 * the default setting is false here for optimum safety.
 */

'display_permission_in_exception' => false,

/*
 * By default wildcard permission lookups are disabled.
 */

'enable_wildcard_permission' => false,

'cache' => [

    /*
     * By default all permissions are cached for 24 hours to speed up performance.
     * When permissions or roles are updated the cache is flushed automatically.
     */

    'expiration_time' => \DateInterval::createFromDateString('24 hours'),

    /*
     * The cache key used to store all permissions.
     */

    'key' => 'spatie.permission.cache',

    /*
     * When checking for a permission against a model by passing a Permission
     * instance to the check, this key determines what attribute on the
     * Permissions model is used to cache against.
     *
     * Ideally, this should match your preferred way of checking permissions, eg:
     * `$user->can('view-posts')` would be 'name'.
     */

    'model_key' => 'name',

    /*
     * You may optionally indicate a specific cache driver to use for permission and
     * role caching using any of the `store` drivers listed in the cache.php config
     * file. Using 'default' here means to use the `default` set in cache.php.
     */

    'store' => 'default',
],
];
```

As you can see, my pivot tables have been set to: `users_has_permissions` and `users_has_roles`

Comment: can you share the table name which you created in database

Comment: @Boni Sure, let me update the question.

Comment: @Boni Done, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem, apparently you can't change the key name in the `config/permission.php` file, so I had:

```
/*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models permissions. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'user_has_permissions' => 'user_has_permissions',

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models roles. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

        'user_has_roles' => 'user_has_roles',
```

I just set the key from the array to what it was at the beginning:

```
/*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * table should be used to retrieve your models permissions. We have chosen a
         * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
         */

    'model_has_permissions' => 'user_has_permissions',

    /*
     * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
     * table should be used to retrieve your models roles. We have chosen a
     * basic default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
     */

    'model_has_roles' => 'user_has_roles',
```